# Would JSDOM work to setup a projects exuberant ctags?

Tags: javascript, vim, exuberant-ctags, zombie.js, jsdom

Looking forward towards excellent javascript ctags support kept me thinking if a project like http://zombie.labnotes.org/ could be used to setup ctags to keep a vim user happy.

Comment: What would be the relationship between zombie.js and ctags? It's a clever testing environment, not a parser. And ctags is already a kind of parser anyway. Did you try DoctorJS in place of ctags? I hear it's quite cool.

Comment: Zombie might not play any role in the end. Basically I saw two options 1) JSDOM 2) PhantomJS (headless webkit) to parse JS to infer its structure.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, none of the projects you are citing are parsers or have anything to do with ctags.

- [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) let's you run your script as if it was run by a webkit-based browser. It won't output an analysis of your code, it will just execute it. You can use it to do a `toSource()` or a `isPrototypeOf()` on a function but that would be rather pointless.
- [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) is an implementation of the DOM to use within your script. It can't be run as an external tool so it can't be used to generate `tags` or analyse your code.
- [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) is a testing framework that simulates a browser for you. Like JSDOM, it can't be run as an external tool and it has no ability to analyse your code.

You can feed your current script to phantomjs with `:!phantomjs %` or use zombie or jsdom in your script but none of it will help you have a better idea of the structure of your code or jump to the definition of a method.

However, if you use either zombie or jsdom or whatever other library in your project you can generate their respective `tags` files and add them to your .vimrc like this:

```
autocmd FileType javascript     set tags+=path/to/a/library/tags
autocmd FileType javascript     set tags+=path/to/another/library/tags
```

If what you want is a better/more modern `tags` generation you can try DoctorJS' [jsctags](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs) or look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790623/how-can-i-make-vims-taglist-plugin-show-useful-information-for-javascript) for a more hackish way to make ctags work for you. As far as I know, these are you only options right now.

Comment: The hazy vision was as follows:

1) Typing in a variable followed by a dot should bring up good autocompletion for javascript.
2) Achieve this by loading all javascript in the background with tools like JSDOM, then inspect the objects properties and methods.

Open-ended details:
- How to get matching line number for the scripts without resorting to regular expressions?
- How to best inder autocompletion for this. within object/function scope?
- Sensibility.

Comment: All the tools necessary for "good autocompletion" are available: ctags and/or jsctags for tags generation, autotag.vim for on the fly update of your tags file... JSDOM and the other tools you have mentioned are of no use in this context: you can't use them to parse your script and output its map or structure as they are not meant to do that. I'm sorry but I think you are completely overthinking the problem.

Comment: My experience with ctags has been duplicates and missing definitions, and jsctags has failed in some way (barfed on syntax or never finishes). I will keep at trying all the options. It just hasn't been as straightforward given the options you mentioned and the results have always been unsatisfactory.